# Linking MinGW64 libs with MSVC 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, mingw, libs

I am trying to link my self compiled libraries (zlib, SDL, SDL_Mixer, SDL_Image, PCRE, ...) (.dll.a, not static) which I've compiled with MinGW 4.7.2 now with MSVC 2010 (x64), this works fine, but when I try to start the application, I am getting strange errors like "deflateInit2" was not found in SDL_Mixer.dll (but this should be in zlib.dll...). What could be causing this? If I link them with MinGW then everything works fine, without any flaws. Do I have to convert my *.dll.a files to *.lib files, so MSVC can use them properly? Do I have to take care about the link order?

Before someone asks, why I am not using the official libraries, It's because they do not work properly with MinGW 4.7.x, they are always corrupting the stack with MinGW 4.7.x.

Screenshot of the weird MessageBox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgo7o.png

Comment: Maybe you can tell us the command line being used to link the program.

Comment: sure: http://pastebin.com/74fzrtmJ

Answer (score 1):

Got it solved by my self, by creating *.def exports from the dlls with "dumpbin" and *.lib import libs with "lib /def:lib.def".